# When reverting a file in perforce which version is restored?

Tags: perforce

Suppose I open a file for editing in Perforce. 
Someone else submits changes to that file.
I revert my changes to the file.
Do I now have the file version that was latest when I performed the
checkout, or do I get the new latest version that someone else 
checked in?

Answer (score 2):

Well since no one answered, I had to look it up for myself.See:
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/cmdref/revert.html
"Use p4 revert to discard changes made to open files, reverting them to the revisions last p4 synced from the depot." So my answer is that the file is reverted to
the version that was latest when I opened it for edit.

Comment: Another word for that version is "the have revision", and you can observe it by running 'p4 have' to ask what revision you have. 'p4 sync' is thus the command that changes what you 'have'.